# how to style every html posts differently in css

Tags: html, css

I have 4 posts in my HTML page, they look same except the text content and images and colors of text and background, in the image below you will find the result that i want:

[image]

my question is how can i style every post without creating class css for every post i want just change colors

this i my code

```css
.art-content {
  position: relative;
}
.art-content img {
  width: 100%;
}
.main-content article {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.main-content article:nth-child(2n) {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.main-content article:nth-child(2n+1) {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.main-content article:nth-child(2n) {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.main-content article:nth-child(2n+1) {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.rect-date-even {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: #c2022a;
  width: 75px;
  height: 77px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px 6px 15px 4px;
}
.rect-date-even span {
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: -10px;
}
.rect-info-art {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
.rect-cat {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #c2022a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25px;
}
.rect-info-art p {
  position: absolute;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-height: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 25px;
}
.rect-info-art a {
  position: absolute;
  color: #c2022a;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 70px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 main-content">
  <div class="title-section-bg">
    <img src="assets/img/ombre-title-section.png">
    <div></div>
    <span class="icon-megaphone"></span>
    <h2>Prochainement a Rabat</h2> 
  </div>
  <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 art-content">
    <img src="assets/img/IMG-even1.png">
    <div class="rect-date-even">
      <span>03</span>
      <span>AVR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rect-info-art">
      <div class="rect-cat">Musique du monde</div>
      <p>Rihanna en concert à Mawazine 2015</p>
      <a href="">détails <span class="icon-circle-plus"></span></a>
    </div>

  </article>
  <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 art-content">
    <img src="assets/img/IMG-even1.png">
    <div class="rect-date-even">
      <span>03</span>
      <span>AVR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rect-info-art">
      <div class="rect-cat">Musique du monde</div>
      <p>Rihanna en concert à Mawazine 2015</p>
      <a href="">détails <span class="icon-circle-plus"></span></a>
    </div>

  </article>
</section>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: Use e.g. `article:nth-of-type(1) .rect-date-even { color: green; }`. `nth-child` does not take into account element type or class or whatever - all it ever asks is ***Am I the `nth-child` of my parent (regardless of element type, class, id, attributes whatever)?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g.

```
article:nth-of-type(1) .rect-date-even { 
  background-color: green; 
}
```

This selects all elements with the class `rect-date-even` that are descendants to any `article` that is the first `article` inside its parent element.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

`nth-child` (which you have tried) does **not** take into account element name (or class or whatever) - all it ever asks is

***Am I the `nth-child` of my parent (regardless of element name, class, id, attributes whatever)?***

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: But `nth-of-type` doesn't do that either right, it only looks for simular elements, while `nth-child` takes *all* children of it's parent into account.

Comment: `:nth-of-type` (as the name suggests) takes into account element *type* only.

Comment: Yes, but not based on class

Comment: Which has already been said but you wanted to point out again. What's the point of that?

Comment: Well, saying *nth-child does not take into account element type or class* somewhat implicates *nth-of-type* does take class into account.

Comment: No, it does not. It's just a clarification that besides element type also class, id or whatever does not matter for `:nth-child`. It's just your false assumption to imply that on `:nth-of-type` this would be possible. But since other might be led in the wrong direction too, I inserted brackets to clarify here. Thanks for hinting me.

Comment: thanks guys for answers its work now, i think i should learning better about selectors

Answer (score 3):

Use the `:nth-of-type(n)` pseudo selector to style them individually.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) p {
  background-color: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) p {
  background-color: blue;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div><p>hello</p></div>
<div><p>hello</p></div>
<div><p>hello</p></div>
<div><p>hello</p></div>
```

Comment: thanks robet for helping, i want to change the sub elements of tag <article> is the :nth-of-type do the work? i have <article the parent element and 2 divs child i want to change her style